# Are you yotzei by lighting candles through a grama?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, chanuka, mitzvah, candle-lighting

Does one fulfill the mitzvah of lighting candles (sabbath or chanukah) if done by a grama (indirect action)? [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We-KRSy64r4&sns=em)

Comment: What was grama about that? :)

Comment: The mitzva is an actual lighting not a placement of the light. The same question could be asked by teffeiln if a machine puts it on the arm and ties it,or shecita as well.its a good q .